# Applying to cart a discount of 20% limited to a max amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I Would like in woocommerce cart, that customers will get a 20% discount, but I want to limit the discounted amount to $500 for example.

Is that possible in WooCommerce?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with ease using **`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`** hook and the WC_cart method [**`add_fee()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee). Then if you use a negative fee, it becomes then a **DISCOUNT**.

In this function the discount is calculate from the cart subtotal excluding taxes (and you can easily change it to total including taxes).

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_limited_discount', 10, 1 );
function custom_limited_discount($cart_object) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Here 20 % of discount
    $discount_percent = 0.2;

    // Here the max discounted amount
    $max_discount = 500;

    // Here are some different cart totals
    $cart_subtotal_excl_tax = WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax;
    $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->total;

    $discount = 0;

    // CALCULATION with subtotal excluding taxes
    $calculation = $cart_subtotal_excl_tax * $discount_percent;

    // Limiting the discount to $max_discount
    if ( $calculation > $max_discount ) {
        $discount -= $max_discount;
    } else {
        $discount -= $calculation;
    }

    $discount_text_output = __( 'Discount (20 %)', 'woocommerce' );

    // Adding the discount
    $cart_object->add_fee( $discount_text_output, $discount, false );
    // Note: Last argument in add_fee() method is related to applying the tax or not to the discount (true or false)
}
```

**This code is tested and is fully functional.**

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

> **Note:** Last argument in [**`add_fee()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee) method is related to applying the tax or not to the discount (true or false).

Comment: sir.as like My coupon code is "MAX500" if anyone applied that coupon code then they will get 20% discount from $500 to $2500 and if the cart total is more than $2500 then the customer discounted by max $500 amount.
please concern and guide me through this issue

Comment: @RaviShankar Sorry but in your question you didn't ask this, so please as this answer is the good one related to your question accept it… After that, I have seen your newest question that is exactly what you are asking me here in your comment and I will try to answer it. But for coupons, things are much more complicated, to make it as you would like and may be not possible this way.